# 2 player CLI Tic-Tac-Toe game in python

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

This is a fully functional code that i have just completed today. I just want to know how efficient is this. and how could i improve it or if theres any bugs that i have miss out.

```
import os
from AskUser import ask_user as As
from random import randint

#initialising the board
class Board():
    def __init__(self):
        self.boxs = [' '] * 10
    
    def display(self):
        print(f' {self.boxs[1]}  |  {self.boxs[2]}  |  {self.boxs[3]} \n---------------')
        print(f' {self.boxs[4]}  |  {self.boxs[5]}  |  {self.boxs[6]} \n---------------')
        print(f' {self.boxs[7]}  |  {self.boxs[8]}  |  {self.boxs[9]} ')

    def update_box(self, box_num, key):
        def valid_position(box_num, key):
            return 0 < box_num < 10 and self.boxs[box_num] == ' '
        while not valid_position(box_num, key):
            box_num = As("Please enter a valid position: ", int)
        self.boxs[box_num] = key
   
    def win_solution(self,key):
        if (self.boxs[1] == key and self.boxs[2] == key and self.boxs[3] == key) or\
            (self.boxs[4] == key and self.boxs[5] == key and self.boxs[6] == key) or\
            (self.boxs[7] == key and self.boxs[8] == key and self.boxs[9] == key) or\
            (self.boxs[1] == key and self.boxs[4] == key and self.boxs[7] == key) or\
            (self.boxs[2] == key and self.boxs[5] == key and self.boxs[8] == key) or\
            (self.boxs[3] == key and self.boxs[6] == key and self.boxs[9] == key) or\
            (self.boxs[1] == key and self.boxs[5] == key and self.boxs[9] == key) or\
            (self.boxs[3] == key and self.boxs[5] == key and self.boxs[7] == key):
            return True
        return False

    def tie_game(self):
        count = 0
        for i in self.boxs:
            if i != ' ':
                count += 1
        return count == 9   

    def reset_board(self):
        self.boxs = [' '] * 10

board = Board()
Turn = randint(0,1)

#Introduction 
def clear_screen():
    os.system('clear')
    print('Welcome to the TicTacToe simulator')
    #Displays the board
    board.display()


while True:
    if Turn == 1:
        #Updates the board after input
        clear_screen()

        #For X Player
        x_move = As('X, Choose a position between 1 - 9 : ',int)
        #Put x input into the board
        board.update_box(x_move, "X")
        Turn = 0
        #Updates the board after input
        clear_screen()
    #Check for win for X or tie
        if board.win_solution("X"):
            print('Congrats, X you have won')
            Turn = 3
        elif board.tie_game():
            print('This is a tie game')
            Turn = 3
        else:
            pass

    elif Turn == 0: 
        clear_screen()
        #For O Player
        o_move = As('O, Choose a position between 1 - 9 : ',int)
        #Put o input into the board
        board.update_box(o_move, "O")
        Turn = 1
        #Updates the board after input
        clear_screen()

        #Check for win for O or tie
        if board.win_solution("O"):
            print('Congrats, O you have won')
            Turn = 3
        elif board.tie_game():
            print('This is a tie game')
            Turn = 3
        else:
            pass

    else:
        p_again = As('Do you want to play again? (Y/N) : ').upper()
        if p_again == "Y":
            board.reset_board()
            Turn = randint(0,1)
            continue
        else:
            exit('Game is over')
```

This is the AskUser function

## Function to check for the user input

```
def ask_user(message, type_= str, valid=lambda x: True, invalid_message="Invalid"):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = type_(input(message))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
        if valid(user_input):
            return user_input
        else:
            print(invalid_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Matrix indexing

The `display` function is a handful. It's often better to use a matrix library like `numpy` to allow better indexing features. For instance,

```py
import numpy as np
one_thru_nine = list(range(1,10))
print(one_thru_nine)
matrix = np.array(one_thru_nine).reshape(3,3)
print(matrix)
print(matrix[0, 1])
print(matrix[1, 1])
print(matrix[2, 2])
```

```bsh
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
2
5
9
```

(Disclaimer: `np.array(one_thru_nine).reshape(3,3)` is not really an ideal way of initializing `numpy` arrays, it's just for demonstration purposes.)

Of course, do beware of [zero-indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

### Magic numbers

As a rule of thumb, avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Try not to put raw integers into code.

```py
return 0 < box_num < 10
```

will be more readable as

```py
min_boxes, max_boxes = 0, 10
return min_boxes < box_num < max_boxes
```

Similarly, I can understand what `Turn=3` does, but it's unintuitive.

### If-Else statements

```py
else:
  pass
```

is redundant. If you don't have anything to do when `if` and `elif` conditions fail, you don't have to add the `else` statement altogether -- unlike some other languages.

That is, you can just do:

```py
while True:
  if condition_one:
    do_something()
  elif condition_two:
    do_something_else()
```

### Class declaration

You don't need to put parentheses next to class declarations if you are not inheriting from a super class.

```py
class Board():
   def __init__(self):
```

can just be

```py
class Board:
   def __init__(self):
```

### Casing

As a general rule of thumb, in classes are in [PascalCase](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase) and everything else (modules, variables, functions, methods) are in [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). As such, `from AskUser import ask_user as As` should be reformatted as `from ask_user import ask_user as as_as` or something similar.

Similarly, things like `Turn` should be `turn`.

### Wrap your module with `main`

In general, if you are not declaring globals, and you declare functions that you will actually call as main (perhaps you're familiar with `C` or `Java`?) you should wrap them in a statement of

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
  board = Board()
  turn = randint(0,1) ...
```

If you don't get into the habit of this, you'll end up executing code you don't want to when you're just importing code from other modules.

### Others

- I don't see the use of `valid` and `invalid_message` anywhere?

Comment: wow thanks for the headers. the valid and invalid_message is to check if the data that is imputed correspond to what i want which in this case must be a number as i added , int in the statement which required the user to input the array index for the tictactoe board. but ofc i could change the type_ = int instead of str  in the Ask_User function but i imported it from the last project which i haven't change it yet.

Comment: Saying `valid=lambda x:True` will always run `if valid(user_input)`.  Try running your code with wrong inputs. You will never print `invalid_message`.

Comment: it will print 'invalid input' if i key in a alphabet as i did this at the end of the statement x_move = As('X, Choose a position between 1 - 9 : ',int). the int would change the type_ into int. and so if non number is key in, it will print 'invalid input

Comment: you mind helping me checking my new code in GitHub it has a single player feature. not really an AI but its able to play on its own. https://github.com/ShreddedPumpkin/Tic-Tac-Toe.git